# How do I use jq to not display keys depending on the value?

Tags: jq

This is the json file. I'm trying to use jq to show the list of APIs and methods.

```
{
  "paths": {
    "/api/A": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "lorem ipsum",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "Guid",
            "description": "Guid"
          }
        ]
      },
      "put": {
        "summary": "Adds or updates an item",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "lorem ipsum",
            "description": "lorem ipsum"
          }
        ],
        "deprecated": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `put` has a key `deprecated` which is set to `true`.
Running `jq ".paths|map_values(keys)" json` returns this

```
jq ".paths | map_values(keys)" json

{
  "/api/A": [
    "get",
    "put"
  ]
}
```

How do I not display the key `put` just because it has child key `"deprecated": true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `keys_unsorted` to get the sub-keys, and update `|=` to replace the former content:

```bash
jq '.paths | .[] |= keys_unsorted'
```

```json
{
  "/api/A": [
    "get",
    "put"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/F3Z-hCGaUaC)

---

To filter out certain elements, you can beforehand update items (not) matching your criteria:

```bash
jq '.paths | .[][] |= select(.deprecated | not) | .[] |= keys_unsorted'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UemNZgd803d)

Or the two steps combined:

```bash
jq '.paths | .[] |= (.[] |= select(.deprecated | not) | keys_unsorted)'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/wLw7o19b45B)

```json
{
  "/api/A": [
    "get"
  ]
}
```

---

Note: Referring to your own approach, if you prefer using `keys` over `keys_unsorted` (the former will additionally sort the output list), and `map_values` over `.[] |=` (they are identical), my approach would translate to:

```bash
jq '.paths | map_values(map_values(select(.deprecated | not)) | keys)'
```